# Flexbox, absolute positioning and 100% height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've run into a bit of a problem while playing around with a flexbox inside an absolute box, which is inside a defined height div (I'll explain along the way).

First off, here's a fiddle to my demo, might be easier to grasp the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/8ub9tyub/

As you can see, when you hover the block, text appears from below but doesn't quite show fully.

I have a main div (let's call it **$main**) for the hover part which is 600x250px with an `overflow: hidden`, and inside it, two divs: title and text (say **$title** and **$text**), which appear after one another (regular flow).

**$title** can sometimes take up two lines, so its height is set to auto.
**$text** is set to 100% height, positioned in relative and set to `display: flex`. Inside that is another div (**$intro**) I positioned in absolute, with a `top: 100%` (which switches to 0 when hovered) and a `align-self: flex-end` in order to keep it at the bottom of **$main**. (this is to keep the text from being stuck to the title - I like it to breathe)

The structure goes like this, basically:

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="title">I'm a title!</div>
 <div class="text">
  <div class="intro"><p>Just a bunch of long paragraphs of text</p></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now, as you can see on my demo, **$text**'s height is set to 100%, but I expected the height to be **$main *minus* $title**'s heights, but here it seems to be just **$main**'s height, which makes the **$text** block overflow, and so when I hover the block to make the text appear, it locks the bottom outside **$main** and cuts off part of the text.

Would anyone have a clue has to how I can make **$text** have the expected height, knowing I can't predict **$title**'s height (and thus can't use `calc()`, at least as for as I know) and ***I don't want to use JavaScript in any way?***

Comment: You gotta love the questions with **broken links**. Please PLEASE always link to something like jsfiddle/plnkr/codepen/etc... So it will at least stay there.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik Right you are! Sorry for being so late but I updated the post with a link to a fiddle instead. Thank you for calling me out on this, I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've gone through and reworked the code without using any heights for the block text or the title text and only using Flex. If you use `display: flex;` **only** on the container that will contain the flexible items within it, then tell each item how to be flexible (ie. `flex-grow: 1;`), you'll get the result you're looking for. [Here's a link to a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/kne3cxhf/) I put together using your initial code and just reworking the code. Let me know if you have any questions or need clarification on anything.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Bitter', Georgia, serif;
  width: 673px;
}
a { color: #161616; text-decoration: none; }
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.home_post_new * { transition: .5s all; }

.home_post_new {
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.home_post_new_text {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(0,0%,100%,0);
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.home_post_new:hover .home_post_new_text {
  background: hsla(0,0%,0%,.33);
}

.home_post_new_block {
  flex-grow: 2;
  position: relative;
  top: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 16px 32px;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 125%;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.75), 0 0 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.75);
}
.home_post_new:hover .home_post_new_block {
  top: 0;
}
.home_post_new_title {
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.625em;
  line-height: 1.333em;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px 8px 16px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.75), 0 0 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.75), 0 1px 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.75);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

.home_post_new_more {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -50%;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 hsla(0,0%,0%,.75), 0 0 5px hsla(0,0%,0%,.75);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  border-color: currentColor;
  border-radius: 0; 
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: hsla(0,0%,0%, .5);
}
.home_post_new_more:hover {
  color: #009884;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.home_post_new:hover .home_post_new_more {
  bottom: 0;
}


.home_post_new_meta {
  width: calc(100% - 600px);
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #009884;
}

.home_post_new_date {
  background: #009884;
  color: #eee;
  padding: 24px 0 0;
  height: 50%;
}

.home_post_new_date_day {
  font-size: 250%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.home_post_new_date_month {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 150%;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-top: 4px;
}

.home_post_new_date_comments {
  color: currentColor;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-top: 32px; 
  padding: 12px 4px;
  border: 1px solid currentColor;
  margin-top: calc(50% - 4px);
}

.home_post_new_text:after {
  clear: both;
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="home_post_new" style="background-image: url(http://geekometric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/fetch_ifl.jpg);">
  <a class="home_post_new_text" href="#">
    <div class="home_post_new_title">[Test] inFAMOUS : First Light</div>
    <div class="home_post_new_block">
      <p>Après les aventures de Delsin, voici inFAMOUS : First Light, qui propose de jouer dans la peau d’un personnage secondaire de Second Son : Fetch. Une aventure qui est, à l’instar de Festival of Blood pour inFAMOUS 2, une extension ne nécessitant pas le jeu de base. Même ville, différents pouvoirs (enfin, pas vraiment), nouvelle histoire et un mode de jeu en plus… De quoi s’amuser un peu ! Mais qu’est-ce que ça vaut ? Voyons cela.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="home_post_new_more">Lire la suite &rarr;</div>
  <div class="home_post_new_meta">
    <div class="home_post_new_date" title="30 novembre 2014">
      <div class="home_post_new_date_day">30</div>
      <div class="home_post_new_date_month">NOV</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="home_post_new_date_comments" title="2 commentaires">2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="home_post_new" style="background-image: url(http://geekometric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/monumentvalley.jpg);">
  <a class="home_post_new_text" href="#">
    <div class="home_post_new_title">[Test] Monument Valley</div>
    <div class="home_post_new_block">
      <p>Profitant d’un crédit de 3€ offert par Amazon sur leur App Shop, je me suis laissé tenter par Monument Valley, ayant entendu du bien du jeu et étant assez intrigué son style. Au pire, je ne perdais rien dans l’affaire… Après plusieurs courtes séances, j’ai terminé le jeu et j’ai donc pu forger un avis assez complet dessus, malgré le fait que Monument Valley soit un « petit jeu », mais il ne faut pas négliger son ambition et potentiel pour autant. </p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="home_post_new_more">Lire la suite &rarr;</div>
  <div class="home_post_new_meta">
    <div class="home_post_new_date" title="28 octobre 2014">
      <div class="home_post_new_date_day">17</div>
      <div class="home_post_new_date_month">NOV</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="home_post_new_date_comments" title="37 commentaires">37</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="home_post_new" style="background-image: url(http://geekometric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/interstellar.jpg);">
  <a class="home_post_new_text" href="#">
    <div class="home_post_new_title">[Séance ciné] Interstellar</div>
    <div class="home_post_new_block">
      <p>Alors comme ça le prochain long-métrage de Christopher Nolan est sorti ? La science-fiction, c’est mon truc, ça ! Je me suis évité tout spoiler possible sur ce film, cette critique en fera autant. J’ai eu le plaisir de voir Interstellar en IMAX, ma première séance dans ce format d’ailleurs, ce qui ne m’a pas déçu. Bon allez, on va voir tout ça, 3… 2… 1… décollage !</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="home_post_new_more">Lire la suite &rarr;</div>
  <div class="home_post_new_meta">
    <div class="home_post_new_date" title="28 octobre 2014">
      <div class="home_post_new_date_day">11</div>
      <div class="home_post_new_date_month">NOV</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="home_post_new_date_comments" title="37 commentaires">37</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="home_post_new" style="background-image: url(http://geekometric.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/johnwick.jpg);">
  <a class="home_post_new_text" href="#">
    <div class="home_post_new_title">[Séance ciné] John Wick</div>
    <div class="home_post_new_block">
      <p>Encore un film qui est sorti de nulle part pour moi, John Wick a attiré mon attention, notamment grâce à la présence de l’immortel Keanu Reeves sur l’affiche. Malgré la minuscule salle (vous savez, celle pour 40 personnes qu’on paie aussi cher que les énormes salles…), j’ai bien pu me mettre dans le film. Chargez vos fusils, on va voir ce que ça donne.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="home_post_new_more">Lire la suite &rarr;</div>
  <div class="home_post_new_meta">
    <div class="home_post_new_date" title="28 octobre 2014">
      <div class="home_post_new_date_day">28</div>
      <div class="home_post_new_date_month">OCT</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="home_post_new_date_comments" title="37 commentaires">37</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="home_post_new" style="background-image: url(http://geekometric.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/tlou_goodies.jpg);">
  <a class="home_post_new_text" href="#">
    <div class="home_post_new_title">[Avis de passage] Goodies The Last of Us : Press Kit, figurine…</div>
    <div class="home_post_new_block">
      <p>Bon, c'est un arrivage qui date un peu, mais je tenais à vous présenter quelques goodies tirés de The Last of Us, non seulement parce que j'adore ce jeu mais parce que ces chouettes objets sont plutôt réussis, et étant donné qu'ils ne sont vus que par mes petits yeux, pourquoi ne pas vous en faire profiter un peu également ? Et ce n'est certainement pas un moyen de faire du contenu en attendant que je fasse mes tests de jeux PS4, je vous assure ! Bon j'ai pris un paquet de photos, c'est cadeau.</p>
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="home_post_new_more">Lire la suite &rarr;</div>
  <div class="home_post_new_meta">
    <div class="home_post_new_date" title="28 octobre 2014">
      <div class="home_post_new_date_day">28</div>
      <div class="home_post_new_date_month">OCT</div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="home_post_new_date_comments" title="3 commentaires">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So let me get this straight you have:

```
<div class='main'>
    <div class='title'>
        <div class='text'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And setting the height of div **text** to 100% sets it to the height of **main** even though it's inside div **title**. I think the problem might be that you did not specify the height of **.title** in your CSS. If you do not specify the height of the title div, then the text division will take on the height of the main div.

Again, just a guess but check for that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking a look! No, actually **title** and **text** are siblings (I wrote the structure in my post above). As I said, **title** has variable height, so I can't specify a fixed value.

You are right about that, though. I tried putting a height in pixels and it looks like it works. Anyway to work around this? With variable height for **title** I can't use that solution I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm hard problem to figure out how to fix. Not sure.

Comment: Thanks for looking into to it. In this situation I think I'll either need JS or flexboxes.